# When is an infinite pro-$p$ group generated by its torsions

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-groups, linear-groups

Let $p$ be a prime and $\mathcal{O}=\mathbf{Z}_p$ or $\mathbf{F}_p[[T]]$, i.e. the ring of $p$-adic integers or the ring of formal power series over a finite field $\mathbf{F}_p$ of order $p$. Let $G\subset {\rm GL}_n(\mathcal{O})$ be a (topologically) finitely generated closed pro-$p$ subgroup containing no open solvable subgroup, and let $T(G)$ denote the set of elements in $G$ of finite order.

**Question:** Is it true that $G\neq \overline{\left\langle T(G)\right\rangle}$? That is, $T(G)$ does not generate $G$ as a topological group.

The answer to the question is Yes in the following case:

- If $T(G)$ is a subgroup and $G= \overline{\left\langle T(G)\right\rangle}$ (or $T(G)$ is dense in $G$), then one can show that $G$ must be finite. But $G$ is infinite by our assumption. For example, it's the case when $G$ is a powerful pro-$p$ group or $G\subset {\rm GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ for some integer $n\geq 2$ with $p>n+1$.

Thus we may assume that $T(G)$ is not a subgroup. Note that $G$ must contain a dense free subgroup by [A topological Tits alternative](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2007/166-2/p04). We remark that the answer to the question is No without the condition that $G$ is a pro-$p$ group. For example, ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ is generated by
$   A=\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 \\
        1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$ and $    B=\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 \\
        1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$ where $A,B$ has order $4,6$ respectively.

Comment: The answer is NO for $\mathcal{O}=\mathbf{Z}_p$. For any odd prime $p$, any integer $n\geq 2$ with $p<n+1$, the Sylow $p$-subgroup $G$ of $SL_{n}(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ is a insoluble $p$-adic analytic hereditarily just-infinite pro-$p$ group. Since $G$ is insoluble and $T(G)$ is nontivial, $T(G)$ will generate a non-trivial normal subgroup which must be open. In this way, we obtain an insoluble $p$-adic analytic group $T(G)$ which is generated by its torsions.

Comment: When you say $G$ contains no open solvable subgroup, do you mean open with respect to the topology on $G$?

Comment: @KentaSuzuki Yes.